# implication from a probability of central limit theorem is not clear

Tags: probability

I found this part of a solution,

$P(p - 1.96  \frac{0.5}{\sqrt(n)} \leq \overline{X} \leq p + 1.96  \frac{0.5}{\sqrt(n)}) = 0.95$

$ \implies 1.96\frac{0.5}{\sqrt(n)} = 0.01$ *(I don't get this  implication part)* Given that $\overline{X} = \frac{X_1 + ... + X_n}{n}$ with $X_i$ is a Bernouli distribution with $1$ if success and $0$ if failure, and $p = 0.5$.

Can you explain how we got to that implication?

Comment: Is the aim to get $\bar X\approx p$ within about 2 digits after the dot? And the second formula used to get a minimal $n=98^2$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to estimate the expectation $p$ via the mean value. The question now is how many single measurements have to enter the mean so that the expectation value is correct to about 2 digits after the dot with $95\%$ certainty,
$$
P(|\bar X-p|\le 10^{-2})\le 0.95.
$$
It is known that $P(|\bar X-p|\le 1.96·n^{-1/2}\sigma)=0.95$ if the single $X_k\sim N(p,\sigma)$. From your formula, $\sigma=0.5$. Thus one needs
$$
1.96·n^{-1/2}·0.5\le 10^{-2}\iff \sqrt{n}\ge 98.
$$